# While loop crashes when using higher numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, crash

I'm trying to make a simple credit card repayment calculator script but seem to be having a problem with a "while" loop. It works for low numbers, but when you start putting in higher numbers it freezes the browser, then you have to quit and reopen.

Here is the JavaScript (jQuery) I have:

```
$('#calculate').click(function()
{
    var currentBalance = parseFloat($('#current_balance').val().substring(1)); // substring so it doesnt grab the £ sign
    var interestRate = parseFloat($('#interest_rate').val());
    var interestType = $('#interest_type').val();
    var monthlyPayment = parseFloat($('#monthly_payment').val().substring(1));
    var totalInterest = 0;
    var interest = 0;
    var months = 0;

    while(currentBalance > 0) // while there is still a balance on the card run the following
    {
        interest = (currentBalance/100)*interestRate; // find interest amount for this month

        currentBalance = currentBalance+interest; // add the interest to the balance

        currentBalance = currentBalance-monthlyPayment; // subtract monthly payment from balance

        totalInterest = totalInterest+interest; // total amount of interest paid
        months++;
    }

    var years = parseInt(months / 12);
    var remainingMonths = months % 12;

    totalInterest = Math.round(totalInterest);

    $('#clear_balance').val(years+' years and '+remainingMonths+' months');
    $('#interest_paid').val('£'+totalInterest);
});
```

and here is my HTML:

```
        <table id="card-info">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="current_balance">Current balance</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="current_balance" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="interest_rate">Interest rate</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="interest_rate" />
                        <select id="interest_type">
                            <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                            <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="monthly_payment">Monthly payment</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="monthly_payment" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button id="calculate">Calculate</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
        <table id="results-info">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="clear_balance">Time to clear balance</label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="clear_balance" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="interest_paid">Total interest paid</label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="interest_paid" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's a "higher number" $1? $100? $99999999999? JS-in-browser does have execution time limits for loops before browsers decide it's a fatal infinite loop and start getting cranky.

Comment: I don't know anything about JavaScript, but you have a closing `div` before an opening `div`. Presumably you just forgot to copy and paste them in.

Comment: thanks Chris, yeah just didn't quite catch that opening div when copying from my code ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't account for the case where the montly payment is insufficient to cover the interest charged each month.

In those circumstances it'll go into an infinite loop, because the loan never gets paid off!

Comment: ahhhhhh! can't believe I missed that! thanks a lot Alnitak! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your currentBalance is positive forever!